# Is there a listing of all the most useful rails gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm new to Rails, and I'm learning that you could save a lot of time by using the right gems. For example, simple_form is great for making forms, and high_voltage is great for making static pages. I've been reading http://learn-rails.com/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-for-beginners and there seem to be a ton of these gems.

So is there a listing of gems that are useful for making Rails apps? Particularly for beginners. (Also, just a thought, but it would be nice if Rails were structured in such a way where these thing were preinstalled, so you could just learn how to do stuff without searching for the right gems all the time.)

EDIT: I've seen blog posts and stuff, but it would be nice if there was a listing that is both 1) somewhat of a consensus, and 2) updated.

Comment: One of the Date Format Gem. Easily we can maintain the date format around the application

https://rubygems.org/gems/date_format

Answer (score 5):

I have found https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/ to be very useful.

They have done a good job of dividing by category, showing last activity, etc..  It is not a list of most popular to least, but thats a tough thing to do since most apps have different requirements.